# having issues installing react-use-autosuggest NPM package

Tags: reactjs, npm-install

I installed the react-use-autosuggest npm package, however, when I'm trying to run it I'm gettign the bellow error message  ''react-use-autosuggest@*' is not in this registry.

I tried running the >npm i --save @types/react-use-autosuggest  but I got the same error message, @types/react-use-autosuggest@*' is not in this registry.
what am I missing?

see below my import

import { useContext, useState } from "react";

import { InputContext } from "../App";

import useAutoSuggest from "react-use-autosuggest";

package.json

`"name": "free-dictionary",

"version": "0.1.0",

"private": true,

"dependencies": {

```
"@grapecity/wijmo.react.all": "^5.20221.857",

"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",

"@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",

"@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",

"@types/react-autosuggest": "^10.1.5",

"autoprefixer": "^9.8.8",

"axios": "^1.1.3",

"react": "^18.2.0",

"react-dom": "^18.2.0",

"react-icons": "^4.6.0",

"react-scripts": "^5.0.1",

"react-use-autosuggest": "^0.3.0",

"tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.2.17",

"web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
```

},

"scripts": {

```
"start": "react-scripts start",

"build": "react-scripts build",

"test": "react-scripts test",

"eject": "react-scripts eject"
```

},

"eslintConfig": {

```
"extends": [

  "react-app",

  "react-app/jest"

]
```

},

"browserslist": {

```
"production": [

  ">0.2%",

  "not dead",

  "not op_mini all"

],

"development": [

  "last 1 chrome version",

  "last 1 firefox version",

  "last 1 safari version"

]
```

},

"devDependencies": {

```
"postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "^5.0.2",

"postcss-preset-env": "^7.8.2",

"postcss-pxtorem": "^5.1.1"
```

},

"peerDependencies": {

```
"postcss": "^8.4.18"
```

}

}`

header.js

```
import { useContext, useState } from "react";
import { InputContext } from "../App";
import useAutoSuggest from "react-use-autosuggest";

const Header = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const { inputValue, setInputValue } = useContext(InputContext);

  const handleInputChange = (e) => setValue(e.target.value);
  const handleSubmit = () => {
    setInputValue(value);
    setValue("");
  };

  const handleInputKeyDown = (e) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      setInputValue(value);
      setValue("");
      return;
    }
  };

  

    const suggestionList = useAutoSuggest(inputValue, handleInputChange);
    
      return (
        <div className="bg-gray-700">
          <div className="container mx auto py-8">
            <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold text-center text-white">
              My Free Dictionary
            </h1>
            <p className="text-center mt-1 mb-10 text-white text-lg">
              Find Definitions for word
            </p>
    
            <div className="flex itmes-center justify-center mt-5">
              <div className="flex border-2 border-gray-200 rounded">
                <input
                  className="px-4 py-2 md:w-80"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Search.."
                  onChange={handleInputChange}
                  {...suggestionList}
                  value={value}
                  onKeyDown={handleInputKeyDown}
                />
                <button
                  className="bg-blue-400 border-l px-4 py-2 text-white"
                  onClick={handleSubmit}
                >
                  Search
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
            {inputValue && (
              <h3 className="text-gray-50 text-center mt-4">
                Results for:{" "}
                <span className="text-white font-bold">{inputValue}</span>
              </h3>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default Header;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-use-autosuggest) the latest version of react-use-autosuggest is 1.0.2, but in your package.json you have `"react-use-autosuggest": "^0.3.0",`. You mentioned you ran `npm i --save @types/react-use-autosuggest`, but have you ran `npm i react-use-autosuggest`?

Comment: Yes I did,  but I'm getting the below error message when running the npm start.  

ERROR in ./src/components/Header.js 108:10-24
export 'default' (imported as 'useAutoSuggest') was not found in 'react-use-autosuggest' (possible exports: __esModule, useAutoSuggest)

webpack compiled with 2 errors

Comment: Can you post the code that you have in Header.js? Including the imports?

Comment: I posted it on top

Comment: have you had a chance to look at it?